# How to make the browser automatically activate the typing field?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, automation

I use online search engines a lot, and I find myself spending much time and effort using the mouse or the pad to select the typing field in the webpage. I wish there could be a way to make the browser automatically activate typing in the typing field of the webpage. Please is there a way to make my Macbook Pro and Chrome do this? Thank you!

Comment: I just use the tab key. No need to take my hands of the keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

To override the behavior of webpages, use the Chrome extensions of
[Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en)
or
[Violentmonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/violentmonkey/jinjaccalgkegednnccohejagnlnfdag).

With these extensions, you can create a JavaScript fragment, called userscript,
to be injected into all or selected webpages.

Below is the example userscript
[auto_focus.user.js](https://github.com/jabbalaci/AutoFocus/blob/master/auto_focus.user.js)
that sets the focus to the right field for
`wikipedia.org`, `imdb.com` and all `www.amazon`.
For doing the same for another website, use the browser's developer tools
to find the name of the field.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        AutoFocus
// @namespace   jabba.laci@gmail.com
// @description Set focus to the specified input field.
// @version     0.0.3
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

(function () {
    var h = document.location.href;

    if (/^http.*wikipedia\.org/.test(h)) {
        document.getElementById('searchInput').focus();
        return;
    }
    if (/^http.*imdb\.com/.test(h)) {
        document.getElementById('navbar-query').focus();
        return;
    }
    if (/^https?:\/\/www\.amazon/.test(h)) {
        document.getElementById('twotabsearchtextbox').focus();
        return;
    }
})();
```

These extensions are a fork of the original
[Greasemonkey](https://www.greasespot.net/).
This website can lead you to many resources for understanding its functioning,
and there is also much to be found via search on the internet.

Comment: Thank you, but I found it difficult. Thanks for the keyword though as I could find a Chrome extension.